# Deseo confirmar si un usuario desea eliminar un registro en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un problema ya que en un `script` que estoy haciendo hay una parte en la que sale un desplegado de resultados después de una consulta y cada resultado tiene a su derecha el botón para eliminarlo. Hasta ahí todo bien.

Lo que pasa es que quiero que cuando el usuario presione el botón "Eliminar" me salga una alerta de `JavaScript` que le pida confirmar si desea hacerlo, sin embargo, esa alerta me sale tantas veces como registros haya (por ejemplo si en la consulta me salen cinco resultados, esa alerta la debo presionar cinco veces, si me salen tres entonces la debo presionar tres veces, etcétera).

Supongo que es porque está dentro del `while` que extrae los registros del `array` pero si saco el código de `javascript` del `while` ya no me funciona.

Ayuda ¿qué hago? Acá dejo el código (mi problema está en las últimas líneas):

```php
while($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
            $fecha3 = date("d-m", strtotime($reg['FECHA']));
            $hora=substr($reg['HORA'], 0,5);
            if ($reg['BANDERA']==1)
            {
                $color="#FCE760";
            }
            else
            {
                $color="#FFFFFF";
            };
            echo "
                <tr>";
            echo
            "
                    <form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='post'>
                        <td bgcolor='$color'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='fecha' value='$reg[FECHA]' />
                            <input type='submit' value='$fecha3' style='background-color:#3296F5;'/>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                    <td bgcolor='$color'><p class='centrado'>$hora</p></td>
                    <th bgcolor='$color'><p class='centrado'>$reg[NOMBRE]</p></a></th>
                    <td bgcolor='$color'><p class='centrado'>$reg[LUGAR]</p></td>
                    <td bgcolor='$color'><p class='justificado'>$reg[TEMA]</p></td>
                    <td bgcolor='$color'><p class='justificado'>$reg[OBSERVACIONES]</p></td>
                    <td bgcolor='$color'><p class='justificado'>$reg[RESPONSABLE]</p></td>
            ";
            if ($reg['CUMPLE']<>NULL)
            {
                echo
                "
                    <form action='procesocumples2.php' method='post'>
                        <td align='center'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$reg[CUMPLE]' />
                            <input type='hidden' name='bandera3' value=true />
                            <input type='submit' name='accion' value='Cambiar' style='background-color:green;'/>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$reg[CUMPLE]' />
                        <input type='hidden' name='bandera3' value=true />
                        <input type='submit' name='accion' value='Eliminar' style='background-color:red;'/>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo
                "
                    <form action='procesocalendario.php' method='post' id='confirmacion'>
                        <td align='center'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$reg[ID]' />
                            <input type='submit' name='accion' value='Cambiar' style='background-color:green;'/>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$reg[ID]' />
                            <input type='submit' name='accion' value='Eliminar' style='background-color:red;' />
                        </td>
                    </form>
                    </tr>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        (function()
                        {
                            var form = document.getElementById('confirmacion');
                            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event)
                            {
                                // si es false entonces que no haga el submit
                                if (!confirm('Confirme si Desea Eliminar'))
                                {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }, false);
                        })();
                    </script>
                ";
            };
```

Comment: Deberías agregar un id a tu botón para poder diferenciarlos uno de otros, y asignar una función eliminar al botón en sí donde sólo le pasas el id

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que todos los elementos formulario los creas con una misma ID "confirmación" entonces tú script se aplica para todos los formularios ya que todos tienen el mismo identificador. Lo que deberías hacer más bien, es trabajar con clases y el iterador "forEach" de Javascript de esta manera podrás aplicarle eventos a cada elemento que tenga esa clase, si le colocas la clase "confirmación" al formulario podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```
    const formularios = document.querySelectorAll(".confirmacion");
    formularios.forEach(form => {
            form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { 
                     if (!confirm('Confirme si Desea Eliminar')){
                                e.preventDefault()
                       }
            }, false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar un id distinto para cada formulario.

Cambia esta línea

```
<form action='procesocalendario.php' method='post' id='confirmacion'>
```

por esta

```
<form action='procesocalendario.php' method='post' id='confirmacion'$reg[ID]>
```

y además debes cambiar

esta

```
var form = document.getElementById('confirmacion');
```

por esta

```
var form = document.getElementById('confirmacion'$reg[ID]);
```

de esta forma lograr generar un id distinto para cada formulario. Espero te ayude esta propuesta. Saludos

Comment: Seguro que **'confirmacion'$reg[ID]** no es un error de sintaxis?

Comment: la idea es cambiarlo dentro de las comillas dobles que tiene la pregunta 
"var form = document.getElementById('confirmacion' + $reg[ID]) "

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, la duda que me surgió es que cierras la comilla y no concatenas (+) $reg[ID] por lo que eso debería ser un error; también podrías utilizar comillas invertidas para hacer el código más limpio de la siguiente forma ` `confirmacion${variable}` `